# How do you determine which submit was used to submit a form with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Keep in mind that the user does NOT have to click the submit nput.  They could tab over to it and push enter.

So considering all ways a form can be submitted, how can you determine which one was used to submit the form inside the submit event.  I have different names on the two submit elements.

Comment: create a hidden input. change the value before submit.

Comment: I know it feels guilty to make a simple comment into an answer, Jonathan, but this to me is a great answer! You might as well get your just desserts for it. ;-)

Comment: I would add that it is possible to give each submit button a unique name (it should already have a value for displaying text), and then you can check which variable exists to determine which form was clicked without using hidden inputs.

Answer (score 4):

Any action that triggers a submit button — be it an actual mouse click or some keyboard action — still triggers a "click" event and still causes the input to be included as a form parameter.

That is, if you see a form parameter with your input field's name and value, you know that that submit button was clicked.

*edit* — if the form submit happens because you hit "Enter" in a text field, the browser picks the first submit button (I think; that seems to be what Firefox does at least). (Wait; scratch that; Firefox seems to find the next "submit" input after the element that had focus when "Enter" was pressed ...)

Thus:

```
<form action='whatever' method='post'>
  <input type='text' name='text'>
  <input name='submit1' value='submit1' type='submit'>
  <input name='submit2' value='submit2' type='submit'>
</form>
```

Hitting "Enter"  in the text field would result in "submit1=submit1" being a form parameter, as would hitting "Enter" when "submit1" had focus. Tabbing to "submit2" and hitting "Enter" would result in "submit2=submit2" being among the parameters.

In either case, only one of the "submit" inputs shows up in the parameter list.

Comment: +1, but a snippet with some comments will make all clearer =)

Comment: And both the "submit"s could have the same "name" and different "value"s.

Comment: How do you see what form parameter was submitted in the submit method?

Comment: You "see" them by testing on the server. How do you handle *any* parameters on the server side?  Your server code should know that it should expect different "submit" buttons, so it can either tell which was pressed by looking for a particular parameter name, or else you can give all the buttons the same name and different *values* so the server just checks the value.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using different names, use different values, e.g:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit A">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit B">
```

You can also use buttons instead of inputs if you'd like the labels to be different from the values.